# How to apply styles on shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, shadow-dom

I'm trying to apply some styles on the shadow DOM. I have this example:

```js
const existingElement = document.getElementById("foo");
const shadow = existingElement.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
const message = document.createElement("p");

message.setAttribute("class", "text");
message.textContent = "Hello World!";
shadow.appendChild(message);
```

```css
#foo::shadow .text{
  color: blue; //not working
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

In the snippet I'm generating a `<p class="text">Hello World!</p>` in the shadow root inside that `<div id="foo"></div>`

I need to apply styles to that class `text` but as it is inside the shadow DOM I can't apply any styles directly. I have tried with `::shadow`, `::ng-deep`, `::content` but no results yet. Any idea?

Comment: You'll want to give https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/ a read through.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah I have checked and I think im doing the same as in the examples but still not working

Comment: looks like I gave you an outdated link, but Kasper gave the right answer. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part for more details on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to find some information about this. And what I can find is that a shadow element is completly seperate from the other parts of the environment. Though as the link below stats

> It’s worth noting that inheritable styles like color, font and line-height are still inherited in a shadow DOM. To prevent that, use all: initial  or, preferably, all: revert once it has better browser support.

[Styling in the Shadow DOM With CSS Shadow Parts](https://css-tricks.com/styling-in-the-shadow-dom-with-css-shadow-parts/#:%7E:text=Base%20styles%20and%20CSS%20resets&text=Shadow%20DOM%20is%20the%20only,same%2C%20even%20in%20a%20messy%20!&text=Even%20it%20does%2C%20those%20styles,effect%20on%20the%20shadow%20DOM.)

I played around with some of your code and made something like this. Which makes the external css have effect over the shadow dom.

```js
const existingElement = document.getElementById("foo");
const shadow = existingElement.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
const message = document.createElement("p");

message.setAttribute("part", "text");
message.textContent = "Hello World!";
shadow.appendChild(message);
```

```css
#foo::part(text) {
  color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Instead of having the setAttribute set a class, you set a [part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part). This seems to get the desired effect that you want. It also needs to be said that you are able to set a attribute in JavaScript to apply style to it directly.